# Why am I getting VBA 'Run-time error 70: Permission Denied' when using ExportAsFixedFormat to PDF but not XPS in PPT version 2009

Tags: vba, pdf, permissions, export, powerpoint

The following code works perfectly in Microsoft 365 PowerPoint version 2007

```
Sub testSavePDF()
    ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "testExportPDF.pdf", _
    FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF
End Sub
```

In Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2209 Build 16.0.15629.20152) 64-bit I get a runtime error 70 - Permission Denied.  I have not found anything specifically related to this on MS site other than this [article by Chris Dietsch](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/changes-in-export-to-pdf-with-sensitivity-labelling-and-encryption-in-office-add-ins/#comments).

I have tried adding 'KeepIRMSettings:=False' and various other flags, and tried using ExportAsFixedFormat2 but get the same result.  If I set

```
FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypeXPS
```

I do not get the error and it writes the XPS file successfully.  I have verified I have permission to write to the directory and at this point I am stumped.

Update: I reverted MS 365 2209 to Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20148) 64-bit and the export to PDF works again.

Comment: How do you know where PowerPoint is trying to save the file? You've included a file name, but no path.

Comment: I have tried it with the file name 'c:\temp\testExportPDF.pdf' with the same result.  Also tried using the path to the 'documents' folder.

Comment: Your update indicates you found a bug. You can report this using _File>Feedback>Send a Frown_ in PowerPoint. Submitting sends the bug report to the PowerPoint programming team. They are unlikely to reply.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but how did you revert your version of MS 365?

Comment: It appears you just follow this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2bd5c457-a917-d57e-35a1-f709e3dda841

Comment: Hi all, Chris from MSFT here, we're looking into this issue as it's been reported via a few mechanisms and are looking into fixes. Thanks for the report and apologies!

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue yesterday with our add-in too but now appears to be fixed. I have 2209 (Build 15629.20156). We think it was impacting the Adobe Acrobat Office Add-in and so MS have fixed it quickly.

Comment: Can confirm - build 15629.20156 has fixed the issue.  I must say I wasn't expecting it to be fixed so quickly - hat tip to MS.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem , my code was working perfect for more than 3 years every day without change , yesterday I have restart my PC (without any update) and suddenly I start getting this error (runtime error 70 - Permission Denied) , I searched a lot and found work around solution to save ppt as pdf using VBA , but I couldn't find the reason why old code stop working

below is the work around code

```
ActivePresentation.SaveAs "C:\testExportPDF.pdf",ppSaveAsPDF
```

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I've just learned that a fix for this problem is on the way.  It'll start rolling out to various release channels soon.  Here are the channels/builds that will include the fix:

Beta Channel: 16.0.15813.20000 or later
Current Channel (Preview): 16.0.15726.20116 or later
Current Channel: 16.0.15629.20222 or later

So if you're seeing this issue, keep hitting File | Account | Update every day or two and checking for one of the build numbers above.

Once you have the update, please check to see if the problem's disappeared for you.

I'd appreciate it if you'd add a comment to this post so I can let my source know that it's working for you.  Thanks.